# Power operator ** on numpy array returns a strange result. Is it a bug?

Tags: python, numpy

From the following Python code:

```
val = 499997
val**3
```

I got a reasonable result: 124997750013499973.

However, from the following code using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
val = 499997
np_val = np.arange(start=val, stop=val+1, dtype=np.uint64)
np_val**3
```

I got a strange result like : array([124997750013499968], dtype=uint64)

Is it a bug of numpy???

Comment: No, it's not a bug, just the limit of a 64-bit unsigned integer. Python's native integers have arbitrary precision, they're not limited to a specific number of bits.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Fair point. OTOH, `499997**3` has a bit length of 57, and `np_val * np_val * np_val` returns the correct value of 124997750013499973. My 1st guess was that maybe Numpy is using logs to do the exponentiation, but `np.uint64(np.exp(np.log(np_val) * 3))` returns 124997750013500208. But if I cast to `np.float96`, eg `np.uint64(np.exp(np.log(np.float96(np_val)) * 3))` I get the correct result. Casting to `np.float64` gives the same result as without a cast.

Comment: @PM2Ring hmm interesting

Comment: `>>> '%.3f' % 499997.0 ** 3
'124997750013499968.000'`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Go home, Numpy. You're drunk! :) That's the same answer as `np.uint64(np.float64(np_val) ** 3)`. And I guess that's better than `np.uint64(np.float32(np_val) ** 3)` which returns 124997747475480576

Comment: @jonrsharpe Does the power operator ** promote integer to float ?

Comment: @MARU It certainly looks like Numpy is using `double` == `np.float64` to perform the `**` operation.

Comment: @PM 2Ring I understood it's not a bug of numpy. Thank you.

Comment: Sure looks like a numpy bug to me. which version of numpy? I have a feeling this was fixed

Comment: `np_val = np.array(val)`, problem solved ;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Nope, not solved - 0d values have the same problems as scalars - see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8809. However, it seems that upgrading to a newer version of numpy will make the numeric errors go away

Comment: @Eric it does solve it, since `np.array(val)` will be a scalar of `dtype=object`, and exponentiation will be what you expect it to be. But I was joking, one doesn't want to work with `object`-dtyped arrays in numpy.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Not on my machine? `np.array(499997).dtype` gives `int32`, not `object`. Did you mean `np.array(val, dtype=np.object_)`?

Comment: @Eric interesting. I originally wrote `np.array(val,dtype=object)` but then I realized that it works on my system (python 3, numpy 1.12) without the `dtype` too. Here `np.array(499997).dtype` is `int64` (64-bit system vs 32-bit?), but most importantly, `np.array(499997)**3` gives `124997750013499973`.

Comment: I'm on master of numpy 1.13. For me, `np.array(499997)` gives `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power`

Comment: @Eric the same warning appears in 1.11 on a 32-bit machine. This makes it almost certain that the behaviour is a function of OS bit size.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: right, but I'm running 64-bit python on a 64-bit machine. And my comment is missing a `**3`, but I assume you guessed that.

Comment: @Eric yeah, I did, I didn't even notice it missing to be precise. But then I wonder what's going on...perhaps my installation is misconfigured and that's why I don't get a `RuntimeWarning`.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been fixed at some point. Trying it now on NumPy 1.17.3 produces correct output:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np 
   ...: val = 499997 
   ...: np_val = np.arange(start=val, stop=val+1, dtype=np.uint64) 
   ...: np_val**3 
   ...:
Out[1]: array([124997750013499973], dtype=uint64)

In [2]: np.__version__
Out[2]: '1.17.3'
```

The bug was most likely caused by some NumPy implementation code casting to float64 to perform the operation and then casting back, as that produces the erroneous output:

```
In [3]: np_val.astype(float)**3
Out[3]: array([1.2499775e+17])

In [4]: _.astype('uint64')
Out[4]: array([124997750013499968], dtype=uint64)
```

I was unable to locate the fix commit or a bug report for the issue, though I did find a [related bug report](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8809) that arose from this question.

Answer (score -2):

This yields garbage:

```
years      = np.arange(1980,2020)
yeartothe3 = years**3
```

while those work:

```
years      = np.arange(1980,2020).astype(float)
yeartothe3 = years**3 

years      = np.arange(1980,2020)
yeartothe3 = years**3.0
```

A real beginners trap... (sigh)

Comment: What is the reason for this behavior? Is it a bug? This doesn't answer anything.

Comment: I don't know the reason, but I hope that this observation can contribute to clarify the fact and isolate the problem. It looks as if numpy has a problem with pure integer potentiation. It works fine though when forcing it to use floating point operations. Did some search on https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues?q=power+is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+  but did not find a related bug.